# How to customize docker build context when deploy a dockized .NET6 lambda using AWS cdk?

Tags: typescript, docker, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am trying to deploy a dockized.NET Lambda application using the **Code.fromAssetImage** method from [AWS CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.Code.html#static-fromwbrassetwbrimagedirectory-props).

My folder structure looks like this

Lambda.Lab - root folder

- Lambda.App - folder contains csprojects

  - `AWSLambda1` - .NET6 AWS Lambda Project

    - `Dockerfile`
  - `AWSLambda1.Data` - .NET6 class library project
- Infra - folder contains cdk project

  - lib

    - `infra-stack.ts` - stack file

I tested building the Dockerfile by running the command below under the `AWSLambda1` project folder successfully. Note that I am using `..` at the end of the command to move the build context up from where the Dockerfile is, in order to get access to the dependent class library `AWSLambda1.Data`

```
docker build -t AWSLambda1 ..
```

Docker file

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:6 AS base

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-bullseye-slim as build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["AWSLambda1/AWSLambda1.csproj", "AWSLambda1/"]
COPY ["AWSLambda1.Data/AWSLambda1.Data.csproj", "AWSLambda1.Data/"]
RUN dotnet restore "AWSLambda1/AWSLambda1.csproj"

#WORKDIR "/src/AWSLambda1"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "AWSLambda1/AWSLambda1.csproj" --configuration Release --output /app/build
# --configuration Release --output /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "AWSLambda1/AWSLambda1.csproj" \
            --configuration Release \ 
            --runtime linux-x64 \
            --self-contained false \ 
            --output /app/publish \
            -p:PublishReadyToRun=true  

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /var/task
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
CMD ["AWSLambda1::AWSLambda1.Function::FunctionHandler"]
```

**So my question is how can deploy the same thing using AWS CDK? I can see the two problems need to be addressed**

1. make sure both `AWSLambda1` and `AWSLambda1` are captured by the CDK project
2. make sure the build context is set to one level up from the `AWSLambda1` project

Below is my `infra-stack.ts` with all my attempts to solve the problem but with no luck so far.

```js
import { Stack, StackProps, Duration, CfnOutput } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
// import * as sqs from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-sqs';
import * as lambda from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';
import * as path from 'path';
import { Code, Handler } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';

export class InfraStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const fn = new lambda.Function(this, 'lambda-docker-attempt1', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.FROM_IMAGE,
      handler: Handler.FROM_IMAGE,

      //attempt 1
      //code: Code.fromAssetImage(path.join(__dirname,'../../lambda.app/AWSLambda1')),
      //[100%] fail: docker build --tag cdkasset-b0efaad78ead998b80e6ab6595a21d7fe24c06ec70f65d4e9005540eabf13161 . 
      //exited with error code 1: COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat AWSLambda1/AWSLambda1.csproj: file does not exist

      //attempt 2
      // code: Code.fromAssetImage(path.join(__dirname,'../../lambda.app/'),{
      //   file: '/AWSLambda1/Dockerfile',
      // }),
      //[100%] fail: docker build --tag cdkasset-1005a75db171185bca51ea88ef8b74313d444af0d936e946ebe7493d684ab9dc --file /AWSLambda1/Dockerfile . 
      //exited with error code 1: unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: CreateFile C:\AWSLambda1: The system cannot find the file specified.

      //attempt 3
      code: Code.fromAssetImage(path.join(__dirname,'../../'),{
        file: '/lambda.app/AWSLambda1/Dockerfile',
      }),
      //[100%] fail: docker build --tag cdkasset-1005a75db171185bca51ea88ef8b74313d444af0d936e946ebe7493d684ab9dc --file /AWSLambda1/Dockerfile . 
      //exited with error code 1: unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: CreateFile C:\AWSLambda1: The system cannot find the file specified.

      timeout: Duration.seconds(30),
    });
  }
}
```

I found an old [discussion about DockerImageAsset](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3342) which seems to similar to my problem, but mine is for lambda deployment only.

I am new to AWS CDK, not sure if what I am looking for is possible or now. Any suggestions are very appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to my lovely colleague Alex, it turns 'attempt 2' was the closest answer with a minor change to remove the front '/' for `file` path, which then becomes the actual answer. A complete answer is attached below. Hope this can help with anyone who has the same issue.

```js
import { Stack, StackProps, Duration } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as lambda from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';
import * as path from 'path';
import { Code, Handler } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';

export class InfraStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const fn = new lambda.Function(this, 'lambda-docker-attempt1', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.FROM_IMAGE,
      handler: Handler.FROM_IMAGE,
      code: Code.fromAssetImage(path.join(__dirname,'../../lambda.app/'),{
        file: 'AWSLambda1/Dockerfile',
      }),
      timeout: Duration.seconds(30),
    });
  }
}
```